# Is there a way to set the shortcut icon with CSS, rather than with HTML?

Tags: html, css, favicon

I know how to declare a shortcut icon (the one on the tab) with HTML:

```
<link
     rel="shortcut icon"
     type="image/x-icon"
     href="images/favicon.ico"/>
```

The project I am working on has way too many files (30+) for it to be practical for me to go place this code on every page. So is there a way for me to do the equivalent in a .css file? Or is there a way for me to place the code in one file and have it apply to all of the files?

Comment: nope sorry. you could also put your favicon in the root of your domain.

Comment: consider using a template and generate yoru pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You could use that code snippet on every page, or you could name the image file `favicon` and place it at the root of your server. This will cause the image to be displayed on all of your pages on your domain. This second method is not recommended by the W3C, however.

Source: [W3C - How to Add a Favicon to your Site](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)

Answer (score 0):

Put the icon at the root of your website. The favicon should be accessable at www.yoursite.com/yourfavicon.png

Comment: I don't think that the browser will automatically recognize favicons at that location.

Comment: That's what I did for my website.